# Environment auto-install

Tags: installation, shell-script, environment-variables, bash-scripting

When I work, I often have to switch computers or virtual machines which means that every time I switch, I have to set up my (Linux) environment again.

My question is the following :

- Is there a tool (in contrast to a simple bash script) that I could use, that would automatically set up my environment?

The setup would consist of installing Debian packages, importing the .bash profile (aliases, functions), environment variables, add lines / fill-in config files, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a portable OS on a flash drive.
2. Build a custom distro and boot from cd / dvd.

More information would be helpful.

Comment: Hum, well portable OS or building my own distro isn't really an option. What I'm looking for would be more like a tool that facilitates / replaces bash scripts that chain apt-gets and modify files.